# having a powers of 2 questions

Tags: java

```
    import acm.program.*;

    public class Practice3 extends ConsoleProgram
    {
        public static int powersOf2(int k) {
        int x = 0;
        while (k < 1000) {
            x = k;
            k *= 2;
        }
        return x;   
    }

    public void run()
    {
        println(powersOf2(1));
        println(powersOf2(0));
        println(powersOf2(2));
        println(powersOf2(-1));
        println(powersOf2(3000));
    }
```

I don't think I really get right values from `powersOf2`. Only 512 is displayed when I run program. And if I run it by each `println`, it gives me:

```
512
none
512
none
0
```

Is there something wrong? or values are correct?

Comment: Can you provide a set of examples of input and output of your function? I am not sure to understand what you except.

Comment: He wants `return 1<<k;`, doesn't he ?

Comment: What kind of result do you want to get? As it is now, it actually gives you the correct power of two, less than 1000. Which is 512.

Comment: 1 will give you 512, 0 -> 512, 2 -> 512, -1 -> 512, 3000 -> 0 -- totally wrong, 1,0 and -1 will do infinite loop !

Comment: @CamilleG. 0 will give you an infinite loop, not 512.

Comment: Do 0 and -1 should give me 512? When I run the program, it shows none.. just blank.

Comment: 0*2=0 it always stays 0, so `k < 1000` is never reached -> infinite loop. Same goes for -1:  -1*2 grows negative, so `k < 1000` is never reached -> infinite loop

Comment: @AnthonyGrist well pointed ! Same for 1 and -1 btw

Comment: @Dobyb *You* have to tell *us* what the correct output is for any given input, not the other way around; we don't know what the problem you're trying to solve is!

Comment: @Camille G. 0 and -1 gives infinte loop of course but 1 will give 512 as `1*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 512`.

Comment: @Christoph youre right !

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int powersOf2(int k){
        int x=1;


        while (k > 0){
            x *= 2; 
            k--;                   
        }

        return x;   
    }
```

Comment: You should remove your Note :). "int: The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 " http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Also, I don't understand your if (k<0). Why should powersOf2(-1) return the same as powerOf2(1) ?

Comment: @Maxime Thanks Again. Was overthinking. It must be fine now. Didn't implement for -ve inputs as the method is return an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The method powersOf2 is completely wrong. It will always return the biggest power of 2 less then 1000. You should take into account the input argument and perform as many multiplications by two:

```
public static int powersOf2(int k){
    int x=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
      x *= 2;
    }        
    return x;   
}
```

Comment: what if I want to leave the method and get the answers from those powersOf2(1) and below, is it still possible?

Comment: @Dobyb I don'y get what you need exactly. Please provide example input and output

Comment: Are you sure that his code is doing that? Try with k = 3 for instance, it will give : 3, 3*2, 3*2*2, etc. It's not a power of 2.

Comment: @Maxime how could this code give 3*2*2 ?! It returns 1*2*2*2=8 when k = 3.

Comment: @Christoph I am not talking about Ivaylo's code (that he has just added after my comment) but about OP's code.

Comment: @Maxime I'm so sorry! You're right 3 will return 768.

Comment: @Maxime The method is called `powersOf2` so we're assuming it's supposed to calculate the kth power of 2. The question doesn't actually state what the problem they're trying to solve is, what the correct output for a given input is, etc - so it's possible this answer isn't correct, but until the question is fixed there's no way of telling.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I am just saying that the current function provided by the OP is not returning the biggest power of 2 less than 1000. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

It won't always return 512. It depends on your initial parameter.
If you pass `k` as a parameter, it returns `k*2^n` which is less than 1000 and `k*2^(n+1)` is more than 1000. (so with parameter 0 method will loop forever)

So if you pass 3, as its parameter it would return 768 and if you pass any number between 501 and 999 the method will be your initial parameter.

For negative number the method multiples the input parameter by 2, until a underflow occurs, if the result of underflow is greater than 1000 it will return the last negative number, otherwise, it will continue the iterations with same exact logic as a positive parameter less than 1000.

So what do you expect your program do?

Answer (score 0):

You are always multiplying `k` by 2 until it exceeds `1000`. So, for all `1000 > k > 0` it returns `512`, otherwise it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your program goes into infinite loop because when you try to call the method with 0 as input. k is always 0 and it is always less than 1000. You need to exclude 0 in your program because it does not make sense having powers of 2 for 0

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to take care of the special cases- for 0, it should be 1, for negative, you should treat it as a negative power, hence you should use double instead of int for your variable. And here is the code:

```
public class Practice3 extends ConsoleProgram
    {
        public static double powersOf2(int k) {
        double x = 0;
        if(k == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        double answer = 2;
        if(k>0){
            for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                answer *= 2;
            }
            return answer;
        } else {
                    answer = 1;
            for(int i = 0; i > k; i--) {
                answer /= 2;
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public static int powersOf2(int k){
    int x=1;
    for (i=0; i < k; i++){
        x*=2;
    }
    return x;   
}
```

Comment: Please, don't copy/paste the answer of Ivaylo.

Comment: No. I just do by my own.

Comment: Well it is redundant ... and 5 minutes too late.  (Oh ... and wrong too!) Delete it.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you have indeed forgotten to declare the variable `i` in your loop.